# Can the Dolphin browser be configured so that the toolbar doesnt scroll along with web pages?

Tags: browser, dolphin-browser

Can the Dolphin browser be configured so that the toolbar doesnt scroll along with web pages?

As you scroll down a web page the browser toolbar scrolls off the screen. Is there a means of fixing its position?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason why you don't want the toolbar to scroll with the webpage is because you don't want to scroll up when you want to type a new address. I don't use Dolphin so I can't tell by first-hand experience, but according to [this](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/12180-address-bar-dolphin-browser.html), you can double tap anywhere on the page to show the toolbar so you don't need to scroll up to type addresses.

Comment: your guess is correct - PC browser implementations function this way because it's more intuitive.  Toolbars and content are two separate things; the movement of the page shouldn't impact the toolbar.  If this happened in a word processor it would be a usability nightmare.  Double-tapping on the page doesn't show it toolbar; it adjusts the text to switch between the initial zoom level and a zoom level which fits the screen with word wrapping.

Comment: @Matt: true, but in a 3.7" screen, having a large address bar obscuring the already scarce screen space is an even worse usability nightmare (people spend more time reading a page than typing on the address bar); usability design is a series of tradeoffs, that's why some people live by a certain browser while others just can't stand it. btw, have you tried the other alternatives mentioned on the page I linked? Otherwise, use the stock browser or Opera Mini/Mobile; I know personally that the standard browser and Opera brings up the address bar when you press Menu button.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hard menu key on your device to get the tool bar back.

Comment: you mean the capacitive touch menu button?  There's no option to get the toolbar back from there.